# Polymer 3 build yields 0-byte my-app.js

Tags: polymer

I seem to have encountered a problem similar to [this](https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-route/issues/231).

file **my-app.js**:

```
import {PolymerElement, html} from "../node_modules/@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js";
import "../node_modules/@polymer/polymer/lib/elements/dom-if.js";
import "../node_modules/@polymer/app-route/app-location.js";
import "../node_modules/@polymer/app-route/app-route.js";

class MyApp extends PolymerElement {
...
}
customElements.define('my-app',MyApp);
```

file **polymer.json**:

```
{
    "entrypoint":"index.html"
    ,"shell":"src/my-app.js"
    ,"builds":[
        {
            "preset":"es5-bundled"
            ,"addServiceWorker": false
        }
    ]
}
```

command **polymer build** produces file **my-app.js** with 0 byte. All other built files look correct according to my naked eyes (at least they are not truncated to 0 byte).

I then re-built the application with the following "dev" **polymer.json**:

```
"builds":[
    { 
        "name": "dev",
        "addServiceWorker": false,
        "js": {"minify": false, "compile": false},
        "css": {"minify": false},
        "html": {"minify": false},
        "bundle": false,
        "addPushManifest": false
    }
]
```

The built **my-app.js** looks correct with this "dev" configuration. However, browser's **sources** window highlights with red under score the first of the followings lines:

```
import {PolymerElement, html} from "../node_modules/@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js";
import "../node_modules/@polymer/polymer/lib/elements/dom-if.js";
import "../node_modules/@polymer/app-route/app-location.js";
import "../node_modules/@polymer/app-route/app-route.js";
```

and **console** window prints this strange message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@polymer/polymer/polymer-legacy.js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".          (index):1
```

I have searched all my **.js** files and directory **../node_modules/** and have not found any file containing **polymer-legacy.js**.

Helps will be much appreciated.

**EDIT**
Thank you for the attention!
These weird symptoms are caused by the stale polymer 1.6.0 which was installed in **/usr/local/bin/polymer** using [yarn](https://www.polymer-project.org/blog/2017-08-23-hands-on-30-preview) .
These issues are gone with polymer 1.7.2.

Comment: So you already tried running `polymer build` with `--module-resolution=node`?

Comment: @Umbo Thank you for the help. These issues are gone with polymer 1.7.2.

Comment: In my case, "clear browser cache" fixed it.